# Error message when starting App

Tags: android, logging

I have done some updates to the code and went to run on my phone for testing when an error message pops up stating "unfortunately,Campfire Songbook has stopped working".

Below is the logcat menus if someone can tell me what the problem is would be great.

> 07-23 21:18:26.782    2787-2787/com.songbook.noo.sttrfsongbook
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.songbook.noo.sttrfsongbook, PID: 2787
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)'
>   on a null object reference
>               at com.songbook.noo.sttrfsongbook.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:39)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2820)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:277)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:84)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:251)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1089)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1374)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

Comment: please add your code to question

Comment: Did you migrate from Sherlock action bar to AppCompat? Add the Activity code so we can help you.